# In Swift-iOS How I catch User Authentication erros in AWS Cognito?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying aws cognito user pool and got stacked in the user sign up process. I already configured my user pool and are executing the sign-up method, but I can find a way to get the error code returned by aws services. Here my user pool instantiation, that is working fine:

```
let poolConfig = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(
                 clientId: userPool_clientId,
                 clientSecret: userPool_secret,
                 poolId: userPool_id)

AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.registerCognitoIdentityUserPool(with: poolConfig,
                                                          forKey: userPoll_App)

userPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: userPoll_App)
```

Then, in my view controller I have a Button whit a @IBAction with this:

```
    if userPool != nil {

        let attName = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()!
        attName.name = "name"
        attName.value = userNome

        let attLast = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()!
        attLast.name = "family name"
        attLast.value = userSobrenome

        let attEmail = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()!
        attEmail.name = "email"
        attEmail.value = userEmail

        var result:Bool = false
        userPool!.signUp(userNome,
                         password: userPwd,
                         userAttributes: [attName, attLast, attEmail],
                         validationData: nil).continue({(task:AWSTask!) in

                            if (task.error != nil) {
                                print (task.error!)
                                result = false
                            } else {
                                result = true
                            }

                            return nil

                        })
```

After that code, I test the result to see if it is true or false and take the appropriate action. But...

I'm having different errors in this process and I need to evaluate this errors in development time. For example, the first error that I got was because I misconfigured the AWS region. Ok! Game on!! But the second error was because the password informed by the user did not passed the validation of the pool. In this case, I want to know the error was because the validation process and inform the user to take the appropriate action. I do not want to have this logic in the iOS app. The task.error object just give a localized description property and it is not very helpful.

By the way: I'm using Swift 3.2, iOS 10.2, aws-ios-sdk2 and Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.error.code` will contain a code you can compare to values in [this enum](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Constants/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.html). Look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html) for the particular error codes that can be returned by SignUp.

Comment: Add an error extension to handle cognito exceptions. Refer this link https://gist.github.com/Catherine-K-George/11a94271bd0cff282e019cd2613d089b

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand on behrooziAWS's answer.

In Swift 4 you can match the error code with enums like AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.TheErrorType.rawValue.

Here's a tip for searching your error type, just type "AWSErrorType" and Xcode's autocomplete would show all the enums and then you can look through them.

Here's a code I use.

```
AWSobject.AWSfunction().continueWith { task -> Any? in
    if let err = task.error as NSError? {
            switch err.code {
            case: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.userNotFound.rawValue:
                 // Handle case
            default:
                 // Handle all other cases here
            return nil
        }

        // Do stuff on success!
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is good to mention that you need to `import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`.
Thank you and behrooziAWS for the answers!

Comment: Refer this https://gist.github.com/Catherine-K-George/11a94271bd0cff282e019cd2613d089b